MDriven Framework file Modlr.config - can it be ignored from git?
Using MDriven Framework, can we safely ignore modlr.config from git? It seems to be modified whenever I even just open the model editor, without changing anything. Does it contain anything that's important for the project or source code?
If it should be committed to git, is there any way we can avoid "noise" (nonsense) changes?

Yes. As I understand it, it actually only contains the last opened model and some further transient information. We have ignored it from git and everything works fine. Now everybody gets his personal config file.

Not sure why this answer got a downvote...? It sure was helpful to me to know that another long-time MDriven developer has been ignoring the file without problems.
